# How can I replace a character in a string only if it's followed by a uppercase letter?

Tags: javascript, string

I am trying to replace a specific character ( "," -> this is the specific character in my case) in a string only if it's followed by a uppercase letter, but no matter how I try it doesn't work. Does anyone know a good way of doing this ?

Comment: try `str.replace(/,(?=[A-Z])/g, '...')`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const p = 'The ,quick brown ,Fox jumps over the lazy Dog.';
console.log(p.replace(/,([A-Z])/g, 'xxx$1'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var str1 = "test,Test";
    var newstr ;
    var index1 = str1.indexOf(',');
    if(str1.charAt(index1+1) == str1.charAt(index1+1).toUpperCase()) {
      var newstr = str1.substr(0, index1) + "*" + str1.substr(index1+1 , str1.length);
     
    }else {
     newstr = str1;
    }
    console.log(newstr);
```